# calculate hh:mm:ss in loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hello I would like to add up different times

when i run this script i have this output:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('"c:\MediaInfo.exe --output=General;%%Duration/String3%%\r\n c:\testmp3\*.mp3"') do (
echo %%f
```

)

have it this output:

```
00:03:21.613
00:02:53.740
00:02:56.143
00:01:47.493
```

I would like to add all this up to a sum. I tried this script

```
@echo off
set total=00:00:00.000
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('"c:\MediaInfo.exe --output=General;%%Duration/String3%%\r\n c:\testmp3\*.mp3"') do (
set /A total=%%f+%total%
)
echo %total%
```

unfortunately i have this error message:

```
Missing Operator
Missing Operator
Missing Operator
Missing Operator
total 0
```

in the end i only want minutes and seconds in a variable %total% exampl: 10:97

Comment: The `SET` command cannot do date math, time math or floating point math.  Pick a different scripting language if you want to do this more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

As Squashman said, inside batch files you cannot do time arithmetics by default.

However, you might build up the functionality inside your batch file yourself with some diligence.
I think you need the following starting points:

**Cutting the timestamps:** The time output must be cut into hours, minutes, seconds, nanoseconds parts. This can be done with `%variablename:~X,Y%` where X is the starting index position (starting at 0) and Y is the length you want to cut (see `set /?` for the documentation).
Example: From `00:03:21.613` to get the minutes you would do something like `set minutes_track=%input:~3,2%`.
Inside the for loop you need to put a `set input=%%f` beforehand. The direct way like `%%f:~3,2%` is not possible (or I don't know how at least).
This approach is dependent on the format of your output, of course. It relies on the fact that all parts are padded with leading zeros and are only 2 digits long (except the last part which has always three digits?). If this is not always the case you need to put more logic into the parsing. Maybe a separate splitting at colon and dot is necessary (like so `for /f "delims=:." %%p in (....) do ( ... )`; see `for /?` in that case).

**Adding up times with wrap around:** You can use the "mod or modulo" `%` and "division" `/` operators to add up sums wrapping around at `60` (seconds). See `set /?` and `if /?` for the documentation sources.
Basically you would compute your total of minutes and seconds like this:

```
set /a seconds_new=(%seconds_total% + %seconds_track%) % 60
set /a minutes_new=(%minutes_total% + (%seconds_new% / 60)

set /a seconds_total=%seconds_new%
set /a minutes_total=%minutes_total% + %minutes_new%
```

**Break down**:
***mod*** gives you the remainder, for example `79 % 60` would result in `19`, whereas
***div*** gives you the full division result in integers, for example `79 / 60` yields `1`.
With this you get the desired "`79` seconds are `1` minute and `19` seconds", which you can add up for your total time.
Same goes for computing hours from minutes if you want to add that feature as well. And if you take `% 1000` and `/ 1000` you can even add up the nanoseconds to seconds beforehand. Also very long tracks which have an hour part must be considered. I leave these as exercise for your script to build ;)

**Important:**
Since these computations will be done inside a for loop in your case, remember to use delayed expansion of variables and replace `%variable%` with `!variable!` everywhere in my examples above (see `setlocal /?`).